# Count bytes written to file by FileUtils.copyURLToFile?

Tags: java, apache-commons

How can I count the number of bytes written by Appache Commons `FileUtils.copyURLToFile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since copying file from url takes time and you already have Apache Commons on your classpath, you might want to use `ConcurrentUtils` class for your problem.

```
long lengthInBytes = ConcurrentUtils.constantFuture(downloadFile()).get();
```

where `downloadFile()` method provides an implementation, which returns length of file in bytes

```
public Long downloadFile() throws IOException {
  File target = new File(fileName);
  FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), target);
  return target.length();
}
```